# Add node-postgres to webpack with vue

Tags: node.js, postgresql, webpack, external

I try to install PostgreSQL with Vue, Node and Webpack.
I use this boilerplate

https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack

and

```
npm install pg
```

https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres

As soon as I enter `import pg from 'pg'` I get this error message.

```
These dependencies were not found:
* dns in ./node_modules/pg/lib/connection-parameters.js
* fs in ./node_modules/pgpass/lib/index.js
* net in ./node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js
* pg-native in ./node_modules/pg/lib/native/client.js
* tls in ./node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js
```

pg must be set as external in the webpack Config. That's exactly what I can't do.
If I write the following:`externals: [{ pg: true }]`
I get this error message under Chrome:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: pg is not defined
    at eval (webpack-internal:///41:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:996)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
    at fn (app.js:89)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///40:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:990)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
    at fn (app.js:89)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///38:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:977)
```

how to enter pg correctly in the webpack config?